# Cursor to all notification sounds

Tags: android, notifications, cursor, ringtone

I use this code to get ***Cursor*** to all ***ringtones***

```
RingtoneManager rm = new RingtoneManager(context);
            Cursor c = rm.getCursor();
```

It works well, but what I need is to get ***Cursor*** to all ***notification sounds***.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rm.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)` before you get the cursor.